# Shiny app deployment error in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

Iam deploying my shiny app to shinyapps.io & all my app files(app.r,www) are all stored in my dropbox. I have loaded the rsconnect command then published the app to my account. The deployment process is successful but when I go to my app url I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred
The application failed to start (exited with code 1).


Attaching package: ‘DT’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    dataTableOutput, renderDataTable


Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    box

Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 1.3-4, (SVN revision 766)
 Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
 Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01
 Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal/2.1
 GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
 Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015, [PJ_VERSION: 492]
 Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
 Linking to sp version: 1.3-1 

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union



Attaching package: ‘raster’

The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    select

Error in value[[3L]](cond) : Cannot open data source
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Comment: Double check that you are referencing your data files correctly. Can you share your code?

Comment: I am referencing my data files directly form my dropbox. code:                       
countor<-readOGR(
  dsn="C:\\Dropbox\\2018\\www\\Elevation Contours",
  layer="25m interval rough contours")


#loading sewer shape file
sewer<-readOGR(
  dsn="C:\\Dropbox\\AquayaLEARN 2018\\www\\Sewer map",
  layer="Sewer line WGS84")

 #loading LIAs shape file
 mp<-readOGR(
   dsn="C:\\Dropbox\\2018\\www\\LIAs",
   layer="m1")
 
#loading  water treatment plants shape file
 treat<- readOGR(dsn="C:\\Dropbox\\ 2018\\www\\treatment plants",
                 layer="Nk_Sewer_newcrs")

Comment: Actually the problem was that I was using absolute referencing instead of relative.Fixed it & it worked!!